# What is this cylinder looking thing in the drain line?

Tags: plumbing, tub

The house is 1950. There is a round cylinder in the drain line with a cap. under the floor is where it is located. What is this called and can I get it out of the drain system?

Comment: A photo would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a **drum trap** - so while cleaning it out might be good, removing it is generally a bad idea unless you are [replacing it with another type of trap.](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,20252981,00.html) Which you may well need to do, as they do rot out eventually, I'm just trying to head off at the pass the idea that it would be OK to remove it without putting a different trap there - is it leaking?